# PDO sqlsrv connection failing silently

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, connection

I'm trying to connect via PDO to a SQL Server database as follows:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$addr;Database=$db", $userName, $pwd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

But I'm getting nothing at all in response.  All that happens is that the output stops running when it hits the $dbh = new PDO(...) line.

I've searched high & low, and found slightly similar problems, but nothing that quite fits the bill.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know that you have PDO installed?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I found the solution in a very loosely related thread, which was to change the connection string from:
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$addr;Database=$db", $userName, $pwd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
to:
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$addr;Database=$db;ConnectionPooling=0", $userName, $pwd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));